# Download NASA satellite data using RCurl in R

Tags: r, download, rcurl, ncdf4

I am trying to download a `ncdf` file using `rCurl`. Can anyone provide any advice on why this is not working?

```
require(RCurl)
require(ncdf4)

url <- "https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODIS-Aqua/Mapped/Seasonal_Climatology/4km/sst/"
filename <-"A20021722014263.L3m_SCSU_NSST_sst_4km.nc"

download.file(paste0(url, filename),destfile = paste0("~/Desktop/", filename), method="curl")

setwd("~/Desktop/")
files<-dir(pattern="*.nc")
f<-nc_open(files[1])
```

> Error in R_nc4_open: NetCDF: Unknown file format
>
> Error in nc_open(files[1]) :
>
> Error in nc_open trying to open file A20021722014263.L3m_SCSU_NSST_sst_4km.nc

Comment: maybe this is the correct address? https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/A20021722014263.L3m_SCSU_NSST_sst_4km.nc

Comment: @M.Viking yes, perfect thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the file downloaded is an error file in XML format? If you open it in Notepad, you'll see it contains stuff like

> Sorry, an error has occurred. Use the back button to return to the previous page or go to the [Ocean Color Home Page](https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov)

Are you sure that the filename you're wanting to download actually exists in that URL?